# Counting Equivalence Classes of Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have to find all of the equivalence classes of a graph with $5$ nodes and $4$ edges and count how many are possible for each class. I have found that there are $6,$ and I know what each is. But, there are supposed to be $10$ choose $4$ or $210$ graphs between all six and I am only getting $180.$ I was wondering if there was a general way to count the number possible for each graph?

In the picture below, for the first class with $4$ edges I have $5,$ for the second I have $60,$ for the third I had $5,$ the fourth I have $20,$ the fifth I have $60,$ and for the last I have $15.$

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you told us how you arrived at 180 we could help you find where you made your mistake? I get $$5+60+60+60+15+10=210.$$

Comment: Yes, 4 edges is the same thing. I'm getting 5+60+60+20+5+5+15

Comment: I'm sorry, I double counted a class so I have 6 classes adding to 175. In the picture in my question, for the first class with 4 edges I have 5, for the second I have 60, for the third i had 5, the fourth i have 20, the fifth I have 60, and for the last i have 15.

Comment: Did I undercount in 3 or 6?

Comment: Ah. Ok so the last is 5 choose 3 or 10. So that means I have a class with 60 and a class with 15 left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First class: $\boxed{5}$ is correct.

Second class: $\boxed{60}$ is correct.

Third class: First, there are $5$ choices for the isolated node. Next, there are $3$ ways to make a $4$-cycle out of the remaining $4$ nodes; namely, pick one of the $4$ nodes arbitrarily (it doesn't matter which), and there are $3$ choices for the node to be opposite the chosen one in the cycle. So the number of graphs in this class is $5\times3=\boxed{15}.$

Fourth class: There are $5$ choices the node of degree $3,$ then $4$ choices for the node of degree $2,$ then $3$ choices for the node of degree $1$ which is adjacent to the node of degree $2$; so the number of graphs is $5\times4\times3=\boxed{60}.$

Fifth class: $\boxed{60}$ is correct.

Sixth class: There are $\binom53$ ("$5$ choose $3$") ways to choose the $3$ nodes for the triangle, so the number of graphs is $\binom53=\boxed{10}.$

The total number of graphs is
$$5+60+15+60+60+10=210=\binom{10}4.$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the concise and clear explanation. I understand where I made my mistakes in the counting.

Comment: Then for 5 edges on 5 vertices would the size of the classes be 12, 30, 30, 60, 60 and 60?

Comment: Yes, that's right.